# php add array element to array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I use PHP 5.5, but my working knowledge is very limited - I am only just learning. I cant' get my code to work.

I have an array EP with 20 values. I shuffle these values for every new visitor of the site, so they are always in a random order.

```
$EP = array(30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220);
$EP = shuffle($EP);
```

I have an array of other arrays

```
$P[] = [81,102,74,157,93,106,0,0]
$P[] = [71,102,76,157,93,106,0,0]
$P[] = [91,102,74,7,93,106,0,0]
$P[] = [56,100,89,15,93,106,0,0]
```

20 in total

What I need is that every element of the EP array is used one time, and then a 0 added at the end, so it looks like this:

```
$P[] = [81,102,74,157,93,106,0,0,$EP(0),0];]
$P[] = [71,102,76,157,93,106,0,0,$EP(1),0];]
$P[] = [91,102,74,7,93,106,0,0,$EP(2),0];]
$P[] = [56,100,89,15,93,106,0,0,$EP(3),0];]
```

so that all 20 array elements of EP are used.

My code which worked, until I add the EP array and added EP(1) etc in my other arrays.:

```
<?php

$Return = array();
$P = array();
$S = array();
$F = array();

$EP = array(30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220);
$EP = shuffle($EP);


//ts1
$P[] = [81,102,74,157,93,106,$EP(0),0];
$S[] = [this series is not important fo rmy question];

//ts2
$P[] = [184,0,0,0,0,0,0,105,$EP(1),0];
$S[] = [..];

//ts3
$P[] = [0,0,0,0,0,$EP(2),0];
$S[] = [..];

//and so on till time series ts20
//for loop below worked until I added the EP series, so it must have something to do with how I call the EP elements from the array.

for($i=0; $i<count($P); $i++)
{
    $Return[] = $P[$i];
    $Return[] = $S[$i];
    $Return[] = $F[$i];
}

die(json_encode($Return));

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two things going wrong:

- [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) doesn't return an array. It returns a bool. When you do `$a = shuffle($a);`, `$a` will be true or false - not a shuffled array. Do instead: `shuffle($a);`.
- When you want to refer to an index in an array, don't use `$a(10)`. Use `$a[10]`. See [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

After changing that, it should work (tested).

Answer (score 0):

You can push to the array

```
array_push($P, $EP);
```

This will add a new array element to $P;

Comment: `$P[] = $EP` is the same

Comment: Hi Arindam, thank you for your answer. with array_push I dont think I can control that every one of 20 P series will get one element from 20 EP elements, and that at the end every element of EP is used one time.